# How to access the leaf or root bean from the ConstraintValidator.isValid method?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, bean-validation

Is there a way to access the leaf or root bean from the `ConstraintValidator.isValid` method? If not, are there any workarounds?

Thank you.

Marcos

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, the reason being that there is no bean instance when invoking `Validator#validateValue()`.

Comment: Regarding workarounds, could you describe what use case you are trying to address?

Comment: Yes, I can understand, but I don't know why to sacrifice such an important information just because of the validateValue method. Most part of the time we call only the validate and validateProperty methods. If the bean information wasn't available we would know that the method being called was the validateValue method. I don't if it's just me, but this specification seems a little incomplete. Sometimes we need more information in the isValid method that is not provided by this specification.

Comment: If I had this information I would not need to use threadlocal to pass contextual information. This is not elegant and is error prone. By the way, the specification should address the need to pass some contextual information to the validate methods if some want to. I think that many people request this, as the information provided in the ConstraintValidator.isValid method is sometimes insufficient to do the validation.

Comment: As a example of a use case where you need the leaf bean is if your entity has some property that needs to be unique in the whole table. If you had access to the bean in the isValid method you could do a lookup in the database using JPA, for example, to check if there's already another entity with the same property value in the database (In Brazil CPF properties sometimes need this validation). We could use the entity id to do the lookup. This is my use case right now.

Comment: We thought for a while about this, but couldn't find a way to make it reliably working in all cases. Assuming there was a way to access the bean, every constraint validator would have to deal with the case that it isn't there. Likely this would be forgotten in many cases, causing the constraint to fail when being invoked during `validateValue()`. And if it is taken into account, what would you do in this case? You'd always need a fallback approach anyways. That being said, you can of course implement a class-level constraint if you need access to the entire bean.

Comment: Regarding a uniqueness check, you might be interested in [this class-level constraint](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AccessingTheHibernateSessionWithinAConstraintValidator) decribed in the Hibernate Validator wiki.

Comment: All this just makes think about how important is the `validateValue()` method. Maybe it should not exist in the first place as it disables more important validations. It just seems like an unnecessary method used only in very exotic situations.

Comment: `validateValue()` is used in UI validation where you want to validate values entered by the user before propagating them to the model. E.g. JSF 2 makes use of this. This doesn't seem that exotic to me. Also other validations are not made impossible by this, just use a class-level constraint as discussed earlier.